# How to run a command before deploying in render

Tags: node.js, package, command, openai-whisper

I am building a web app and I npx whisper-onnx-speech-to-text in my backend, locally it works just fine but when I want to put my project in render to publish it, I run into a problem because that package needs to run this command: "npx whisper-onnx-speech-to-text download" after it and then select a model from multiple one, this is simple locally but render doesn't give a way to access a terminal and work with it,

I tried to make the build command as follows yarn && npx whisper-onnx-speech-to-text download but I still need a way to give it the desired model afterwards

Is there anyway to achieve that?